# Openshift: oc login failed

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

There is an openshift cluster in our organization, and I always get an error when using "oc login" on my computer. However, I can log in successfully by using others' computers. The error is the following:

> oc login 
>       error: dial tcp: i/o timeout - verify you have provided the correct host and port and that the server is currently running

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the matching version of the `oc` client for your cluster? Do you have a proxy setup on your computer, and do you need to exclude use of the proxy for your internal systems?

Comment: @Wei Dong, did yyou find solution? Same issue here

Comment: Hi @JimC Actually it works after this issue is proposed. I didn't do anything. I don't know what happened :)

Answer (score 0):

Please make it sure you install the "Kubectl" in macOS first.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
oc login <web interface url>
```

for example

```
oc login https://192.168.1.100:8443
```

OR

```
oc login https://myopenshift.com:8443
```